# How to load mtl files with gltf in react-three-fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, gltf, react-three-fiber

I have downloaded a set of files from a site and exported the glb, gltf, and mtl files in blender. I can get the glb or gltf file to display in the react-three-fiber scene, but I am not sure how to get the textures to display properly. I have come across a couple of demos but they seem old and what would not work.

Here is how I load the file.

```
import desk from '../../assets/desk.gltf'; // or .glb file

const [gltf, set] = useState();
useMemo(() => new GLTFLoader().load(desk, set), []);
return gltf ? <primitive object={gltf.scene} scale={[0.05, 0.05, 0.05]} position={[0,0,1]} 
rotation={[Math.PI/2,Math.PI,0]}/> : null
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you are mixing two topics. `MTL` files are relate to the `OBJ` format. Meaning the visual aspects of the assets's geometry are stored in one or more external `MTL` files.

`glTF` does not have separate files for that. Material definitions are directly defined in the `glTF` JSON manifest. So loading the actual glTF asset is sufficient for loading material definitions.

Comment: OK. That makes sense. I am having some issue where every file that I download from the various sites shows as grey with no texture. When I import them into Blender, the same thing happens even though those files are present in the folder.

Comment: When using glTF it's best to work with `glb` files since all assets (glTF JSON manifest, binary files, textures) are packed in a single binary archive.

Comment: Blender's default Layout viewport shows grey with no texture initially.  You have to click "material preview" or visit the shading panel to see textures in Blender.